# import data from one table and insert it into another

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `product_myob` and `products`. What I want to do is to import *products* from `product_myob` when the *import button* is clicked to table `products`. Table `products` already contains some *products*.

I try to execute below query but the table is not updated. Please help me with the code.

```
INSERT INTO products(myob_id, myob_displayID, Name)
  SELECT UID,displayID,itemName 
  FROM product_myob 
  WHERE UID NOT IN (SELECT myob_id from products);
```

Comment: Any error details you have ?

Comment: foreach($products as $key =>$value)
 {
       $productcheck  = "select count(PID) from product_myob where displayID = '" . $value->Number . "'";
    $procheckrs =  mysql_query($productcheck);
    $proavailable = mysql_fetch_array($procheckrs);
       $proavailablecnt  = $proavailable[0];
    
 if($proavailablecnt<1)
  {
   //above query
   mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
   
   //echo "Item ". $value->Name . " (" . $value->Number .") added successfully <br/>";
   
  }

Comment: The data types of myob_id, myob_displayID, Name of products table should match those of UID, displayID, itemName of product_myob table. If so first try executing the query directly on database.

Comment: It's always a good idea to first execute the query directly on database. Then you can see the issues if any.

Comment: datatypes are matching

Comment: i tried executing above query directly into database bit result is 0.

Comment: @user3513872 show your table definitions and sample dataset by adding an example of [*fiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code that you can use. Using ***MySQLi*** though because ***MySQL*** is deprecated already.

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION AND CHANGE THE NECESSARY HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD AND DATABASE */

$connection=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM product_myob");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$myobid=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['UID']);
$myobdisplayid=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['displayID']);
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['itemName']);

/* CHECK IF DATA IS ALREADY IN THE products TABLE */

   $result2=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE myob_id='$myobid' AND myob_displayID='$myobdisplayid' AND Name='$name'");

   if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)==0){

   mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO products (myob_id, myob_displayID, Name) VALUES ('$myobid','$myobdisplayid','$name')");

   } /* END OF IF MYSQLI_NUM_ROWS($RESULT2) IS 0 */

   else {
   echo "Data has already been inserted before.<br>";
   }

} /* END OF WHILE LOOP RESULT */

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a unique check on your products table and you are inserting some duplicate data if this is the case then you can ignore duplicate values by below query, even you don't need to check UID in product table as this query automatically ignore it. Other wise elaborate your question:

```
INSERT ignore INTO products(myob_id, myob_displayID, Name)
  (SELECT UID,displayID,itemName 
  FROM product_myob);
```

Comment: what is ignore in ur sql stmt

Comment: please check updated answer as you don't need to check UID in product table as this query automatically remove duplicates...if myob_id is primary key or a unique constraint on it..which should be on it as per my assumption..